# Source files not in project directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Have two projects in directory defined below. Also I have two files -`PurchaseOrder.wsdl.c` and `PurchaseOrder.wsdl.h` that I need to share between projects.

```
C:\proj\PurchaseOrderClient //project `PurchaseOrderClient` directory
C:\proj\PurchaseOrderService //project `PurchaseOrderClient` directory
C:\proj\ //shared files `PurchaseOrder.wsdl.c` and `PurchaseOrder.wsdl.h` directory
```

I have added header and source files to appropriated filters.

It is fine with header file if I define in project code like `#include "..\..\PurchaseOrder.wsdl.h"`

But how to tell to project where is `PurchaseOrder.wsdl.c` file? I suppose that is why I have linking problems.

Comment: What linking problems? You should explain further.

Comment: You really don't have to do this if this is your base project (and only project). Right click on your project > properties. You will find VC++ Directories. You need to add your source directory location where it says `Source Directories`. Could you please print your LINK error so that we know if you are pointing us to the right direction.

Comment: Add `PurchaseOrder.wsdl.c` file to the project using "Project - Add existing item" function. It allows to add files from any directory, not only the project directory.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for pointing on linker errors. Some libs were missing.